# smtp funciona pero no llega correo laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel-5

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Laravel dice que mi correo ya fue enviado, pero en la bandeja de mi correo no ha llegado nada y el correo que utilizo para enviar los mensajes tampoco registra el correo enviado, que podria estar sucediendo.

asi tengo mi `.env`

```
MAIL_DRIVER=sendmail
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=-------.-------@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=***********
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Quedo atento y muchas gracias por su ayuda

Answer (score 1):

Has probado a configurar con los mismos datos el archivo `mail.php` que se encuantra en: `/config/`.

Cuando he usado `Laravel`, lo tenia configurado en los dos sitios. Espero que te sirva esta información